# Marshal c# struct member

Tags: c#, struct, marshalling

I am not sure how to interpret LayoutKind.Explicit in MSDN:

> *The precise position of each member of an object in unmanaged memory is explicitly controlled. Each member must use the FieldOffsetAttribute to indicate the position of that field within the type.*

Does a *member* mean the same as defined in §11.2 of the *CSharp Language Specification* (so methods **can** be present **and** are marshaled), or does it mean *field* as in §10.5, or does it mean *variable* as in §5?

Comment: Ask only one question.

Comment: I disagree. These questions are coherent enough to be answered in one place.

Comment: Okay I changed to one question

Comment: I'll add them here: 1) can fields be excluded from the marshaling 2) if the struct has methods can i still marshal its fields (seems very weird if the method is considered part of the struct...)

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that each "member" must be marked with `FieldOffsetAttribute`, which supports field member only.

Comment: Can there be non-field-member members?